# Работа с картой Asp.net

Tags: google-maps, asp.net, c#, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте.

Делаю сайт для бронирования такси. На старице сайта должна быть карта (например, с помощью сервиса google-maps), пользователь чёлкает на две точки на карте, и между ними строится путь (по дорогам), далее на станице сайта должны отобразиться названия двух адресов (точек, по которым нажал пользователь) и путь в километрах между этими точками.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать в asp.net?
У google-maps есть такой функционал? Или нужно как-то это писать самому? 
Может, есть какие-нибудь библиотеки для работы с картами?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас MVC, то есть такое решение: [Карты Google в ASP.NET MVC 4](http://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/3.php).

Answer (score 2):

Привет! Честно говоря, не знаю причем тут asp.net. Такой функционал, разумеется, есть у гуглокарт и яндекс карт. Например, у [яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/router-docpage/). Надеюсь, чуть-чуть помог.